# Update body of a "FailedMessages"-document in ravendb (servicecontrol instance )

Tags: nservicebus

I want to be able to retry a failed NServicebus message but with an updated body.

I have successfulle updated the body tag in ravendb (the servicecontrol instance) of a "FailedMessages" Document
*but*
the api still returns the old body (from the bodyUrl). So when i retry the message from our custom document viewer the body is still the old when reaches the Handler.

Is it possible to update the body?

-EDIT-
When you do a retry using the Servicecontrol API. Is it the message that is in the error queue that is resent or is it data collected from the servicecontrol ravendb instance that are put together and sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to update the body of a message. It is possible after all.

Here is some sourcecode from ServiceControl:

```
DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.PutAttachment("messagebodies/" + bodyId, null, bodyStream, new RavenJObject
            {
                {"ContentType", contentType},
                {"ContentLength", bodySize}
            });
```

Previously I tried to update the FailedMessage document which has a body tag. But I needed to update the Attachment. The bodyId in the above code is not the UniqueMessageId but MessageId found in  ProcessingAttempts -> MessageMetadata -> MessageId.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to update the body of a message, it goes against the basic principle of messages are immutable...

If there is a business reason to modify the data then it should be done by your application logic i.e. a reconciliation process.
Make sense?

EDIT:-

Error messages are processed from the error queue and stored in a RavenDB document, when a retry or a retry batch is invoked the message is composed and sent to the original endpoint that was processing the field message. Just to be clear.

Please note: ServiceControl's API is not a public and supported API...

Comment: Well, yes it makes sense that you are not supposed to edit the message. But in our case it does, we have our own custom made application using the Service control API to view failed messages and to retry them. It would make sence to edit messages there before a retry. Several endpoints in different projects do make use of the service control. If I could I do not want to have dependencies those projects. And since I do have access to the RavenDB database instance where servicecontrol store its data, my thougth was that I should be able to do this. You say It is not possible, please explain.

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your question, hope this makes sense, you can look at the code as it is [open source here](https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl)

Comment: Just found out it is possible. See my answer. +1 for link to source code